# 'vendor/autoload.php' errors, composer is installed globally

Tags: php, composer-php

I installed [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) globally and when I run my mail php example I get the following errors:

> Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emailexample/index.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emailexample/index.php on line 9

I appreciate any advice on resolving these errors.

Comment: try `composer update` command

Comment: Go an check the permissions of your filesystem, that might be an issue.

Comment: @prit.patel composer update brings this: Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

Comment: @Tobias F. which file exactly?

Comment: Please show your "mail php example". Do you have `vendor` directory in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emailexample`?

Comment: @DaisymondChiboora the directory of `vendor` and also the permissions of the `vendor/autoload.php` file.

Comment: @rob006 I don't have vendor directory in my hotdocs/emaileample, why ? because I installed my composer globally thinking it would work from that directory I installed it with any, in which my project resides. not knowing if this is practical or not

Comment: @TobiasF. that directory "vendor" is what I can not find on this Mac but I have composer installed and from my home directory in the terminal I run the composer [option] commands and they are executing with success except composer update or related options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you misunderstood what Composer is and what installing it globally means. Composer is a **tool** for installing dependencies in your project. Installing it globally means that you can use this tool from any place in your system, but it doesn't mean that it will magically resolve all dependencies from all of your project - you need to call Composer manually to declare and install required dependencies.

So if you have `composer.json` file in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emailexample` you should go into your project directory and install required dependencies:

```
cd  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emailexample
composer install
```

If you don't have `composer.json` you need to define your dependencies first. You can read more about it in [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md), and dependencies should be defined in source of your "mail php example" project. But in general you can add dependencies by:

```
cd  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/emailexample
composer require package/name
```

Where `package/name` is name of dependency - you should replace it with real name.

After installing dependencies make sure that you include composer autoloader in your `index.php` - you should have something like this before using any class:

```
require_once __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php':
```